# Loop and sum giving unexpexted result

Tags: c, pointers, sum

## This is my code

*with the help of pointers i try to find and compare the sum of the main and second diagonal of a 5x5 matrix.The numbers are randomly generated*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main {

    int i, s1, s2, j, a[5][5];

    srand (time (NULL));

    printf ("The matrix is:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf ("\n\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            *(*(a + i) + j) = rand ();
            printf ("%d ", *(*(a + i) + j));
        }
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        s1 += a[i][i];          // main diagonal
        s2 += a[i][4 - i];      // second diagonal
    }

    printf ("\n\nThe sum 1:%d\nThe sum 2:%d", s1, s2);

    if (s1 == s2) {
        printf ("They are the same");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the sum of the main diagonal is bigger by 51 than it should be

Comment: As I saw this: `*(*(a+i)+j)` i nearly blanked out... Are you trying to produce unreadable code? You can do this with `a[i][j]` as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I am trying to use only pointers in order to understand better how  pointer arithmetic and dereferencing in 2-D arrays works.

Comment: Proper invocations of `main` are either `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (or with the equally correct `char *argv[]`). Of course you can name `argc` and `argv` anything you like.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2 separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: code should be written for ease of readability and understanding.  This includes the variable names, which should indicate `usage` or `content` (of better, both).

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. I.E.  4, 5.  To make things much simpler for you and much more readable/understandable (especially 6 months down the road) use a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names everywhere in the code.,

Comment: the `int` variables `s1` and `s2` are not initialized, so adding values to them is undefined behavior.  suggest modifying the declaration for those variables to:  `int s1 = 0;  int s2 = 0;`

Comment: to avoid data being displayed on the terminal long after an output statement, like `printf()` is called, always end the format string win th `'\n;` character.

Comment: it is considered a poor programming practice to widely separate variable declarations from where those variables are used.

Comment: the array `a[][]` is not an array of pointers to pointers to int.  so this kind of expression: `*(*(a + i) + j)` will not work as you are expecting.  Suggest:  `*( a + ( i*j ) )

Comment: because `rand()` can be returning any value up to `MAX_RAND` such a summing of an array of values could easily overflow.  Suggest limiting the value, perhaps by using `rand()%10000`  Which would result in a max sum of (approx) 50000.

Answer (score 3):

`s1` and `s2` both are uninitialised. You need to initialize them with `0` before using in statements `s1+=a[i][i];` and `s2+=a[i][4-i];`.

```
int i, s1 = 0, s2 = 0, j, a[5][5];
```

I would also suggest to use

```
a[i][j] = rand();
```

instead of

```
*(*(a+i)+j)=rand();
```

to access array members.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialised s1,s2 to zero

```
s1+=a[i][i];  // main diagonal
s2+=a[i][4-i]; // second diagonal
```

Prior to these statements

Answer (score 0):

### You could do as follow:

1. `*(*(a+i)+j)=rand();` ----> `a[i][j]=rand()%100;`
2. `printf("%d ",*(*(a+i)+j));`  -----> `printf("%d ", a[i][j]);`
3. add `s1 = s2 = 0;`

### Then the following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i,s1,s2,j,a[5][5];
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("The matrix is:\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=rand()%100;
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);  
        }
    }
    s1 = s2 = 0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        s1+=a[i][i];  // main diagonal
        s2+=a[i][4-i]; // second diagonal
    }
    printf("\n\nThe sum 1:%d\nThe sum 2:%d\n",s1,s2);
    if (s1==s2)
    {
        printf("They are the same\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly it is better to use a named constant instead of magic numbers.  So you could define for example named constant `N` for the magic number 5. In this case your program will be more flexible and can be modified easy.

For the sums it is better to use a more larger integer type as `long long int`. Otherwise an overflow can occur.

You should initialize variables near the point in the program where the variables are used. If your compiler supports C99 then you may declare and initialize variables where they are used.

You could limit the maximum value that elements of the matrix can have.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N   5
#define VALUE_MAX   100

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N];
    size_t i, j;
    long long int s1, s2;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    printf( "The matrix is:\n" );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf ( "\n\n" );
        for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
        {
            *( *( a + i ) + j ) = rand() % VALUE_MAX;
            printf ( "%d ", *( *( a + i ) + j ) );
        }
    } 

    s1 = 0ll;
    s2 = 0ll;

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        s1 += a[i][i];              // main diagonal
        s2 += a[i][N - i - 1];      // second diagonal
    }

    printf( "\n\nThe sum 1: %lld\nThe sum 2: %lld\n", s1, s2 );

    if ( s1 == s2 ) 
    {
        puts( "They are the same" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
The matrix is:


55 81 79 14 75 

89 70 41 27 73 

94 14 79 85 45 

66 92 27 90 67 

14 85 79 53 83 

The sum 1: 377
The sum 2: 287
```

Or if your compiler supports C99 then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N   5
#define VALUE_MAX   100

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N][N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    printf( "The matrix is:\n" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf ( "\n\n" );
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
        {
            *( *( a + i ) + j ) = rand() % VALUE_MAX;
            printf ( "%d ", *( *( a + i ) + j ) );
        }
    } 

    long long int s1 = 0ll;
    long long int s2 = 0ll;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        s1 += a[i][i];          // main diagonal
        s2 += a[i][N - i - 1];      // second diagonal
    }

    printf( "\n\nThe sum 1: %lld\nThe sum 2: %lld\n", s1, s2 );

    if ( s1 == s2 ) 
    {
        puts( "They are the same" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```